# Custom Payment Method form block - can't display on checkout page - Call to a member function setMethod() Error

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, blocks, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

I get fatal error while setting up custom payment method block for checkout page

```
`Fatal error: Call to a member function setMethod() on a non-object in 
app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Helper/Data.php on line 106`
```

Here's my Implementation

Payment Method File paths

```
app/code/local/SecurePay/SecureFrame/Block/Form
app/code/local/SecurePay/SecureFrame/controllers
app/code/local/SecurePay/SecureFrame/Model/Standard.php
```

Block Class

```
<?php
     // app/code/local/SecurePay/SecureFrame/Block/Form/SecureFrame.php
class SecurePay_SecureFrame_Block_Form_SecureFrame extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form
{
 protected function _construct()
  {
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('secureframe/form/secureframe.phtml');
  }
}
```

Payment Model

```
<?php
class SecurePay_SecureFrame_Model_Standard extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract {
    protected $_code = 'secureframe'; 
    protected $_formBlockType = 'secureframe/form_secureframe'; //This line thows the error
// other stuff ....
}
```

Also If I comment the line `protected $_code = 'secureframe';` Error disappears but obviously custom payment block does not get set

**Edit:

Config.xml File**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <SecurePay_SecureFrame>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </SecurePay_SecureFrame>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <secureframe>
        <class>SecurePay_SecureFrame_Model</class>
      </secureframe>
    </models>
    <helpers>
      <secureframe>
        <class>SecurePay_SecureFrame_Helper</class>
      </secureframe>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <secureframe>
        <class>SecurePay_SecureFrame_Block</class>
      </secureframe>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <default>
    <payment>
      <secureframe>
        <model>secureframe/standard</model>
        <active>0</active>
        <order_status>pending</order_status>
        <title>Payment via Securepay</title>
        <payment_action>sale</payment_action>
        <test_mode>1</test_mode>
        <merchant_id></merchant_id>

        <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>

        <currency_accepted>AUD</currency_accepted>
        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
      </secureframe>
    </payment>
  </default>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <secureframe>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>SecurePay_SecureFrame</module>
          <frontName>SECUREPAY</frontName>
        </args>
      </secureframe>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

Template file path for phtml file in template directory

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/securepay/secureframe/form/secureframe.phtml
```

What I am doing wrong ?? How to resolve this error and display custom form on checkout page

P.S. Also tried placing the form phtml file outside the `securepay` directory like

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/secureframe/form/secureframe.phtml
```

However error does not get resolved

**Edit**
Here is the code from Helper file which is giving error

```
 public function getMethodFormBlock(Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract $method)
{
    $block = false;
    $blockType = $method->getFormBlockType();
    if ($this->getLayout()) {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($blockType); // This might be causing error, not sure (from helper file reported in error)

        $block->setMethod($method);
    }
    return $block;
}
```

Comment: can you please add your module etc/config.xml file in comment?

Comment: Added config.xml file

Answer (score 2):

When you use a second upper letter in your files and class, things change a litte:

The Block Type Schema: `ModuleName`/`ClassPath`:

`ModuleName`: lowercase when a single name and use exactly the same string when has more than one uppercase letter on name.

`ClassPath`: lowercase when there is a single name or use first letter on lowercase and in all other first letters use uppercase.

So if your block class is: `SecurePay_SecureFrame_Block_Form_SecureFrame`
Change your block type to:

```
protected $_formBlockType = 'SecureFrame/form_secureFrame';
```

Comment: It's interesting to see two approaches from different angles. @Abdul's answer above also recognised that the class name didn't match the $_formBlockType, but whereas you suggest changing $_formBlockType he suggests changing the Block class itself. Though I think he forgot that as well as changing the block class name you have to also change the filename to match.

Comment: Yes. Abdul's approaches just will work if you change the name of module too, from SecureFrame to Secureframe, like this: `SecurePay_Secureframe_Block_Form_Secureframe`. He forgot the ModuleName.

Comment: My approach is based in your initial situation.

Class: `SecurePay_SecureFrame_Block_Form_SecureFrame`. 
Filepath: `app/code/local/SecurePay/SecureFrame/Block/Form/SecureFrame.php`

Comment: Let me know after you try my approach.

Comment: +1 for details about `Block Type Schema: ModuleName/ClassPath:`

However evn changing the $_formBlockType giving the same fatal error
I hav updated the question with snippet from core file, that might be useful

Answer (score 1):

Please change code from

```
<?php
     // app/code/local/SecurePay/SecureFrame/Block/Form/SecureFrame.php
class SecurePay_SecureFrame_Block_Form_SecureFrame extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form
{
 protected function _construct()
  {
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('secureframe/form/secureframe.phtml');
  }
}
```

**TO**

```
<?php
     // app/code/local/SecurePay/SecureFrame/Block/Form/SecureFrame.php
class SecurePay_SecureFrame_Block_Form_Secureframe extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('secureframe/form/secureframe.phtml');
    }
}
```

Comment: Applied. Could not get the error resolved with this change in class name.
Also, I am working on displaying custom payment form, and info block is separate thing which appears on right sidebar. Correct me if I'm wrong
Thanks

Comment: can you please vote me if you are satisfaction with my ans?

Comment: sure, however you are suggesting to change the classname to Block_Info, but i'm stucked in implementing payment form which appears while choosing the payment method

Could you please help me resolve the error as why that is givig me invalid block type fatal error ??

Thanks :-)

Comment: i am updated my ans please see and replace code